# Must be or must not to be files in Git repository

Tags: git, git-flow

I wonder would I need to put in Git remote repository files like config files, for example, file with DB credentials like db host, username, password and so on?Or do I need to put some sort of "stub" files and write something like README where I would point people what they need to do make all works correctly

What would be a strategy about this sensitive staff?

Comment: Maybe .gitignore is what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi! Its not matter how to do this, its matter why and which one. So I am interesting about common strategy for this kind of files

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to put all the credentials in a config file outside the code and **NOT** include this config in the public repository. If you are working with a team in a private environment, you can push this file to the remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

Comments and previous answer focus on credentials and the security implications of putting them in the repo; this is too narrow a focus.

Best practice is to put environment-specific details in a property file so that building in a different environment is as simple as switching property files.  For example if you need a `persistence.xml` file, and if your build tools facilitate some sort of variable interpolation (such as what Maven calls resource filtering), then you can write a single file in your resources directory with placeholders, and provide the appropriate values at build time

One way to make it easy for the build to default to the correct properties for the intended environment is to look for the properties file *outside* the source-controlled source tree; so a developer just keeps his localhost properties at that location, and your build server is set up with the correct files for any given job's target environment.

And as a nice bonus, then you aren't keeping sensitive information (like production database passwords) where anyone with dev access can see them.